# Voltage Rectifier Fails When Doorbell Button Shorts Inputs

Tags: voltage, power, voltage-regulator, esd, short-circuit

I am working on a project that involves powering a 3.3V microcontroller off a doorbell transformer. The design uses a full-wave bridge rectifier (1) to convert the AC voltage from the doorbell transformer to DC, which is smoothed by a capacitor. A switching regulator (2) then converts the DC voltage from the bridge rectifier to 3.3V to power the MCU.

[image: AC input -> bridge rectifier -> switching regulator]

Since the doorbell still needs to function, a switch is used to trigger the doorbell chime. However, I am running into an issue: when the doorbell button is pressed, shorting the AC inputs to the bridge rectifier, it destroys the switching regulator.

One initial thought provided by a [previous question](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/390806/bridge-rectifier-fails-when-ac-inputs-are-shorted/390894#390894) was that the doorbell solenoid created a high voltage inductive kick that was killing the circuit. To prevent this, a bidirectional TVS diode was installed across the doorbell solenoid (3) for ESD supression. The bridge rectifier does not appear to have any issues and continues to function normally even after the switching regulator fails.

[image: Doorbell solenoid TVS diode]

I am working to find a way to allow the doorbell to be triggered without damaging the voltage regulator and I would greatly appreciate any insight into why the regulator might be failing.

All of the datasheets for the components are listed below:

1) [Comchip Technology DF206ST-G](https://www.mouser.com/datasheet/2/80/DF2005S-G%20Thru340567.%20DF210S-G%20RevF-535444.pdf): Bridge rectifier

2) [RECOM Power R-78E3.3-1.0](https://www.mouser.com/datasheet/2/468/R-78Exx-1.0-958279.pdf): Switching regulator

3) [Wurth Electronics 824501751](https://www.mouser.com/datasheet/2/445/824501751-952923.pdf): TVS diode

edit: In a previous question I thought that the bridge rectifier was failing. It turns out that it is actually the regulator failing.

Comment: Wasn't it the bridge rectifier that was failing in your previous question?

Comment: Toglefritz, how is this question different than your original? You originally asked why your rectifier is failing, and you appear to be asking that same thing again. If you have an update to your previous question, edit that instead of making a whole new duplicate question.